# Easiest way to pass a multidimensional array(array of array) into an abject

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass data from an multidimensional array into an object using a constructor.  As of now, I'm basically passing it in position by position and handling the construction in a bunch of for loops.  It works the way I'm doing it, but I'm wondering, is there a better way to do this?

**JS**

```
function Plume(dateTime, huh){
    for(var i = 0; i < dateTime.length; i++){
        this.time = dateTime[0];
        this.zone = dateTime[1];
        this.date = dateTime[2];
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < huh.length; i++){
        this.huh = huh[0];
    }
    this.dateTime = this.date +" " +this.time;
    this.huh = this.huh;
}

var plume = new Plume(file[0], file[1]);
```

I know that if I do a loop on the array `file` itself, I'll simply create a Plume object for every item in the array, but doing it the way I'm doing it now seems to be very inefficient.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  I only want one instance of Plume to be created.

*Note: The array will actually be much larger, but I didn't want to do the entire thing for simplicity's and time's sake*

Comment: Did you try to debug this? Step by step? You'd be shocked by what you see

Comment: @Amit, I have, I see nothing wrong, everything outputs the way it should.  Perhaps some clarification?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop here:

```
function Plume(dateTime, huh){
    this.time = dateTime[0];
    this.zone = dateTime[1];
    this.date = dateTime[2];
    this.huh = huh[0];
    this.dateTime = this.date + " " + this.time;
}

var plume = new Plume(file[0], file[1]);
```

If you can use ES6 features, you can destructure parameters like this:

```
function Plume([time, zone, date], [huh]){
    this.time = time;
    this.zone = zone;
    this.date = date;
    this.huh = huh;
    this.dateTime = this.date + " " + this.time;
}

var plume = new Plume(file[0], file[1]);
```

Comment: Would I still need to input each array item in the instantiation?